# How to continue JSF:RENDER_RESPONSE phase after exception in END PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION

Tags: jsf-2

I want to continue to JSF:RENDER_RESPONSE (last phase in JSF lifecylce) after getting a particular custom exception in INVOKE_APPLICATION phase.

For following action all Six JSF lifecycle phase run:

```
public void save(String actionID) throws Exception
{
}
```

What I am getting in logs is :

```
 START PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
 END PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
 START PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
 END PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
 START PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
 END PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
 START PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
 END PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
 START PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
 END PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
 START PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
 END PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
```

But for following action (**action throwing exception**):

```
public void save(String actionID) throws Exception
{
    throw new FieldMissingException("LLLL");
}
```

I am getting :

```
START PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
 END PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
 START PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
 END PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
 START PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
 END PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
 START PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
 END PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
 START PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-8080-1) #{bandListController.save('Band.Create.Action.Save')}: com.alt.security.exception.FieldMissingException: LLLL: javax.faces.FacesException: #{bandListController.save('Band.Create.Action.Save')}: com.alt.security.exception.FieldMissingException: LLLL
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
.
.
.
END PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
```

Render response phase is not getting executed. 
How to move to next phase after getting exception in APPLICATION Phase.

To  handle Exception globally , I have also created ExceptionHandlerFactory and ExceptionHandler [exceptionHandler-link](http://javalabor.blogspot.in/2011/09/jsf-2-global-exception-handling.html).

```
@Override
public void handle()
    throws FacesException
{
    for (final Iterator<ExceptionQueuedEvent> it = getUnhandledExceptionQueuedEvents().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        Throwable t = it.next().getContext().getException();
        while ((t instanceof FacesException) && t.getCause() != null) {
            t = t.getCause();
        }
        if (t instanceof FieldMissingException) {
            // -->  What should I write here to stop propogation of custom exception to next phase  
            // final FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            // facesContext.responseComplete();
        }
    }
    getWrapped().handle();
}
```

Adding more information about project:
--> web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation=" http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <display-name>AltAdminWAR</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Welcome page -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- JSF mapping -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Map these files with JSF -->

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
        <location>/</location>
    </error-page>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

--> face-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <application>
    </application>
    <lifecycle>
        <phase-listener>com.alt.security.test.LifeCycleListener</phase-listener>
    </lifecycle>
    <factory>
        <exception-handler-factory>com.alt.security.test.ExceptionHandlerFactory</exception-handler-factory>
    </factory>
</faces-config>
```

--> pom file entry for jsf and primeface

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

JBoss Server : jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

Comment: JSF does that already by default. So something in your application is disturbing the default behavior. The cause is not clear from the information provided so far. How can we reproduce your problem when starting off with a completely blank web project with everything set to bare defaults and most recent versions?

Comment: @BalusC thanks for replying. What extra detail should i have to provide?

Comment: @BalusC, I have added detail of environment